# index.html not invoking javascript file

Tags: javascript, node.js, html

I'm making a simple client/server connection via node.js modules and a simple HTML page.

the html page is this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
```

Where the index.js file in the same directory is this:

```js
alert("hello!");
```

This works fine when I manually click on the html page, but when I invoke it using my app.js:

```js
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/web/index.html');
});
app.use('/web', express.static(__dirname + '/web'));
server.listen(2000); 

console.log('Started Server!');
```

by calling

> node app.js

it does not show the alert when the HTML page loads. I just installed node.js and installed the **node express** dependencies in this app after I called "node init" on the project.

Comment: Also, for more clarification,  I can do <script>
    alert("hello!");
</script> in the index.html and the alert will show up on the node server. I just don't know why I can't do the same if I call the script source

Comment: Is the script loading from the server in the network tab?

Comment: The script is in the same directory as the index.html file. I don't know what you mean by "script loading from the server"?

Comment: Look at the network tab on your client and see the path that is being requested for the index.js file. You're likely getting a 404 for the requested resource. I bet it's requesting localhost:2000/index.js which corresponds to nothing on your server.

Comment: You're right, its 404, but why would this be the case? I have it in my app.js to load items from the /web directory?

Comment: smhrjn posted a working example. If you wanted to keep it the way you have it you would have to change the src on the script to "web/index.js"

Answer (score 2):

The path for index.js and static folder does not match. Therfore it fails to load index.js.

This should work:

```
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/web'));
server.listen(2000);
```

Comment: Thank you! I should probably read up on how express works too!

Comment: You're welcome. You can also use `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/web'));`, without any route, if it is supposed to work for all routes.